# Search a list of strings with a list of substrings

Tags: python, string, list, substring

I have a list of strings and currently I can search for one substring at the time:

```
str = ['abc', 'efg', 'xyz']   

[s for s in str if "a" in s]
```

which correctly returns

```
['abc']
```

Now let's say I have a list of substrings instead:

```
subs = ['a', 'ef']
```

I want a command like

```
[s for s in str if anyof(subs) in s]
```

which should return

```
['abc', 'efg']
```

Comment: Have you tried to solve this yourself? Perhaps creating a helper function? Could you please share with us your attempts?

Comment: Have you considered using [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any)? Also, **don't** name your own variable `str`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> s = ['abc', 'efg', 'xyz']  
>>> subs = ['a', 'ef']
>>> [x for x in s if any(sub in x for sub in subs)]
['abc', 'efg']
```

Don't use `str` as a variable name, it's a builtin.

Comment: Any way to edit this so that it prints the substring instead? i.e. the same as (will it be more efficient solution, though?)`for i in range(len(subs)): for j in range(len(s)): if subs[i] in s[j]: print subs[i]`

Answer (score 0):

Gets a little convoluted but you could do

```
[s for s in str if any([sub for sub in subs if sub in s])]
```

Comment: +1... But this would never pass a code review with me :P

Comment: Nor would it pass mine, but hey, give the people what they ask for.

Comment: That is extremely awkward - compare to `any(sub in s for sub in subs)`

Comment: In many cases you would be correct... Take a look at [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) for info on how to recognize instances where your `"give the people what they ask for."` position may not be the correct path.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Oh, Didn't even think of that.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use them one after the other:

```
[s for s in str for r in subs if r in s]
```

---

```
>>> r = ['abc', 'efg', 'xyz']   
>>> s = ['a', 'ef']
>>> [t for t in r for x in s if x in t] 
['abc', 'efg']
```

Comment: This will fail for `s = ['a', 'ef', 'fg']` and return `['abc', 'efg', 'efg']`.

Answer (score 0):

I still like `map` and `filter`, despite what is being said against and how comprehension can always replace a `map` and a `filter`. Hence, here is a `map + filter + lambda` version:

```
print filter(lambda x: any(map(x.__contains__,subs)), s)
```

which reads:

> filter elements of s that contain any element from subs

I like how this uses words that carry a strong semantic meaning, rather than only `if, for, in`